# VBA Compare Arrays different in size and build a new one

Tags: arrays, vba, compare

I have a one-dimension array generated by a listbox of strings I would like to use to match with master 2D array with strings in the first column and numbers in all others. The objective is to create a third array with matching strings and the relevant data from the master. Could not find a better solution from searching here although the subjected is not unknown. Guess I am lost in building the new array.

```
Private Sub ImportSelection()
    Dim i, j, k, m, ListSize As Integer
    Dim arr2() As String
    Dim pArr As variant     
    Dim Size As Integer

    Size = List2.ListCount
    ReDim ListBoxContents(0 To Size) As String

    For i = 1 To Size
        ListBoxContents(i) = List2.list(i)
    Next i

    On Error GoTo eh
    ReDim arr2(1 To List2.ListCount, 1 To 16)

    For i = LBound(ListBoxContents) To UBound(ListBoxContents)
        For j = LBound(pArr, 1) To UBound(pArr, 1)
                If ListBoxContents(i) = pArr(i, 1) Then
                    arr2(k, m) = pArr(i, j)
                    k = k + 1
                    m = m + 1
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
eh:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: What isn't working with your code?

Comment: `pArr` is never assigned a value.

Comment: Why Private? Why are i, j, k, m declared as variant? Why isn't ListBoxContents declared? Why are you using On Error when developing? Why haven't you put any data into pArr? Why are no values assigned to k and m? Provide some sample data of List2 and pArr containing some values you are trying to match so someone can write a working code.

Comment: Looks like you have a lot of questions to answer, OP :P

Comment: VBasic2008 read carefully: i, j, k, m are declared as integer not variant. pArr is kept as private within the userform to preserve the data from a module and pass it from listbox to listbox. Hints from donPablo on the loop resolved all issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the middle part of the code to be -->

```
k = 0  ' need to initialize (and also add headings to row zero)
For i = LBound(ListBoxContents) To UBound(ListBoxContents)
    For j = LBound(pArr, 1) To UBound(pArr, 1)
            If ListBoxContents(i) = pArr(J, 1) Then  ' pArr needs to be J
                k = k + 1   ' got a match, ergo increment the output row
                For m = 0 To UBound(pArr, 2) - 1
                    arr2(k, m) = pArr(J, m)  ' move into col m, from pArr J row
                Next m                
            End If
    Next j
Next i
Exit Sub  ' do not drop thru
```

Also as Comintern sez --> pArr is never assigned a value.

Also, are you getting what you want from

```
Dim i, j, k, m, ListSize As Integer
```

Comment: Works great and I finally understood the nested loops. Have just rectified the m- loop into 

for m= 0 Ubound(pArr, 2)  

to make it work. Thank you also for noticing the pArr unassigned value, which was actually assigned elsewhere in the code as a private property. Dim i, j, k, m, ListSize work also fine.

Thanks again and hope to be of use to help other users once I have stronger VBA foundations.